# Override the canonical URL in custom layout handler

Tags: magento2, layout, seo, head, canonical

I'm attempting to override the canonical URL for a custom handler. I tried adding the following code via XML, but instead of overriding the default canonical URL, I now have both the default and the one I set. Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this? Thank you.

```
<head>
    <link rel="canonical" src="https://mystore/test" src_type="url" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what your layout XML might look like:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="head">
        <action method="addLinkRel">
            <argument name="rel" xsi:type="string">canonical</argument>
            <argument name="href" xsi:type="string">https://mystore/test</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

In this example:

targets the head block.
 adds a link tag with the "canonical" relationship.
https://mystore/test specifies the custom canonical URL.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can create the canonical URL in a custom layout handler in Magento 2:

Create or edit your custom layout XML file. This file should be located in your theme's **app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/Magento_Theme/layout directory.**

In the layout XML file, define your custom layout handler and use the  block to set the canonical URL. Replace {Vendor} and {Theme} with your actual vendor and theme names.

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/{custom_layout}.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!-- Your custom layout handler -->
        <referenceContainer name="head">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="custom_canonical" as="custom_canonical" before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<link rel="canonical" src="{your_custom_canonical_url}" />]]></argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

1. Replace **{custom_layout}** with the name of your custom layout handler.
2. Replace **{your_custom_canonical_url}** with the desired canonical URL you want to set for the page.
3. Clear the Magento cache after making changes to your layout XML files.